# Is it better to use ExecutorService+Runnables or to use Call Enqueue?

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2

Apologies if this is too simple of a question, I am new to using remote data sources.

I assume Enqueue is running on background threads instead of main thread, but which is faster and better for optimization? As I understand using Runnables will take up more code, but I have seen multiple apps built with such a method, is it better than the simpler Enqueue method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Retrofit** will use underlying `OkHttp` to make calls to the server. Enqueue is tested and it is always better to use the globally recognized by developers with performance testing and lots of other aspects around it. It also covers your `ExecutorService` without you having to write the implementation for it. I'll add few points for readers new to OkHttp.

- `new Request.Builder().url(endpoint).build()` creates the request but
  doesn't send anything.
- `client.newCall(request).execute()` sends the request and waits for
  the response, but doesn't download the response, only its headers so
  you can check things like `response.isSuccessful()` immediately.
- `response.body().string()` downloads the body of the response and
  returns a string.

You can push your own implementation of `ExecutorService` like this

```
OkHttpClient.Builder().dispatcher(Dispatcher(executorService)).build()
```